# virtualenv command is not found in Mac OS

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed `virtualenv` using the command `sudo pip install virtualenv` and the installation is successful. Later, when I type `virtualenv`, I get the error message as following,  `-bash: virtualenv: command not found`

The `virtualenv` is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. I see the similar questions in the forum with no definitive answers.

Python is in the location `/usr/local/bin/python` and I have version `2.7.9`. I get the following using `ls -l` command,

[image]
Why do I see the `virtualenv` is not found and how to solve the issue ?

### UPDATE:

I use the command

`ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py` to put the `virtualenv.py`

inside the `/usr/local/bin` folder. Previously, I only did the same for the `virtualenv` file. Now, when I put the command `virtualenv` in the terminal, I get

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: Permission denied`.

I later use

`sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py /usr/local/bin/virtualenv.py`

and the say message keep showing. `which virtualenv` still returns nothing.

Comment: What I suspect is happening is that the virtualenv executable isn't being copied or symlinked to your `/usr/local/bin` folder.  If you can locate the executable inside the `site-packages`, try symlinking it to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: What do you mean ? I just checked inside the `/usr/local/bin` folder and there is no `virtualenv`. Should I copy from the `site-packages` and put inside the 'bin' folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pursuant to @Jason's suggestion, try making the symbolic link for virtualenv in the /bin directory like so:

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Comment: I did that and now I see `virtualenv` inside the `/usr/local/bin` folder. However, when I provide the commands `virtualenv` or `which virtualenv`, nothing returns in the Mac terminal. I closed the terminal and started again. No help with that as well. Now ?

Comment: I can't take this as answer unless it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Check the permissions in the bin folder with `ls -l`.

Comment: If the permissions are insufficient, try a chmod 700 virtualenv

Comment: @Jason, the output I get using `ls l`, I provided that inside the original question.

Comment: @Rome_Leader, after following your suggestion, I get `chmod: virtualenv: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you run both the ls -l and the chmod in the usr/local/bin directory? It doesn't look from your screenshot like you did.

Comment: that screenshot above is not from /usr/local/bin, but rather from the user home directory.  If you're running chmod in the home dir, it will not be able to find the virtualenv execurable.

Comment: Okay, I just run both of the commands in the `/usr/local/bin` directory. I still have the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide a new screen shot of what the ls -l in usr/local/bin shows?

Comment: It provides a lot of info, I can't take the screenshot for all. I provided a partial shot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't re-install virtualenv? Also try to use the latest version of pip (sudo pip install -U pip).

Comment: Do I need to uninstall pip and then to install again ?

Comment: Okay, I follow your instructions, but, no help here. After upgrading the pip, I get the message, `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg`

Comment: But have you re-installed virtulenv after that?

Comment: Yes, I also re-installed the `virtualenv`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the answer will be useful to you, as i see the question is a few month old, but maybe it will be helpful for others.

I encountered the same problem, after installing python3.5 and pyCharm on my Mac. I moved the 3.5 folder from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5`, following [this guide](https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/installing_python_osx/), after disabling the System Integrity Protection first with reboot into recovery mode (boot with ctrl+R), and executing `csrutil disable` in the terminal. After reboot it was possible to move the python3.5 folder, and then i followed the guide, and everything worked like charm. In pyCharm i could choose the version 3.5 from `/System/...` instead of `/Library/...` (*however, i still left a soft link in /Library/... to the /System folder where the python3.5 now was, just in case*), and after adding the path to my zsh i could execute `pip3 install virtualenv`. So far so good.

Next, i tried to create the environment with `virtualenv -p python3 env`, and here i had the same problem as you. It seemed like the path could not be added somehow. Initially i also tried to look in the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` and include it in the $PATH, then also create softlinks to virtualenv.py as you tried too, but finally found that although all the files are in the site-packages folder, the actual executable was in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv`. As the path there was included in my $PATH, i have no idea why it did not execute when typing `virtualenv -p python3 env`, even with sudo as you tried too, but once i typed the full path `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenv -p python3 env`, it worked like charm again.

I still have no idea why, but it worked and now i can move on :)

Hope it helps, and hope someone can explain this better than me.

Answer (score 0):

You are created the symbolic link to the **wrong file**. As far as I know **virtualenv** is installed to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv`, (you can change the numbers for your Python version) so the **command** for creating the **symbolic link** should be:

```
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```